# add 2 search option in datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I want to add 2 search option in my existing panel:
http://103.239.252.98/app_sms_log_panel/home.php

credential is as below:
username: admin
pass: Nopass1234

What I want to add in this is that:
2 search options.

> 1.from date
>   2.to date

what will be the result? according to the searching it will show the required row between the 2 dates.

how can I do this?

Comment: I am not clicking that link, instead add a [mcve]

Comment: ok.. have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to add 2 search options :

**JS**

```
 $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
                var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
                var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column
        if (( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max )) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
             ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    );

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody><tr>
            <td>Minimum age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="min" name="min"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="max" name="max"></td>
        </tr>
```